Angular 17 and standalone component structuring
I am unable to see anything on localhost except footer, header and side-nav components. What am I doing wrong here?
app.component.html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <app-header></app-header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-menu">
        <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
    </div>
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="homePage">Home</a>
    
    <div class="content-wrapper-right">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="modal-footer" class="col-12">
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Above is the app.component.html file.
app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    CommonModule, 
    HeaderComponent, 
    FooterComponent, 
    SidenavComponent, 
    HomePageComponent,
    RouterModule
  ],
  // providers: [ToastrService],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})

home-page.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [HomePageActionsCardComponent],
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrl: './home-page.component.scss'
})

home-page.component.html
<div>
    <app-home-page-actions-card></app-home-page-actions-card>
</div>`

home-page-actions-card
<span class="border-0 ">
    <span class="card shadow rounded border-0 w-100">
        <div class="card-content">
            <div class="card-header custom-class">
                <div class="card-title">
                    Hello There!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body mr-1">
                <div>
                    <span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</span>

I am unable to see anything on localhost except footer, header and side-nav components. What am I doing wrong here?
I want to show home-page-actions-card also but it's not visible.

please share how you configured the routing and boostrap application part, if possible github repo or stackblitz

You are using the standalone version of Angular, have you added "provideRouter(routes)" to the providers array in the ApplicationConfig and defined routes in general?

Really the new angular docs sucks. here indicate how add a router in standalone components, as Marlon says you need add in the array providers the provideRouter when you "bootstrapApplication" the aplication.

looking like you forgot to import HomePageActionsCardComponent in app component.ts
